# Run a sh with Xvfb display using cron?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I am trying to run a `sh` script using cron. This script requires a display.

I have tried:

```
# Xvfb display
/usr/bin/Xvfb :10 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
```

```
15 17 * * * /bin/sh /path/to/script/script.sh > /path/to/log/log.log 2>&1
```

Nothing happened and the `log.log` was not created. How do I check for errors?

Second try:

```
20 17 * * * <user> export DISPLAY=:10 /bin/sh /path/to/script/script.sh > /path/to/log/log.log 2>&1
```

Same result no log file, and I can't see whether it got executed or had issues.

Comment: You can check for messages from cron using `journalctl -u cron.service -xe` for example. Where exactly are you placing the cron command (user's crontab? root's crontab? systemwide /etc/crontab?)

Comment: @steeldriver user's crontab. I ran the command. I see that it tried to execute both times but got this error: `(ubuntu) CMD (ubuntu export DISPLAY=:10 /bin/sh /ibc.paper/twsstart.sh > /ibc.paper/lo
Jun 14 17:28:01 CRON[1659]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`. Not sure why the output didn't go to log file.

Comment: Only the systemwide `/etc/crontab` needs the `<user>` field after the timespec - when you put it in a user crontab (`crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e`) cron tries to execute the username as part of the command - which appears to be what is happening here `CMD (ubuntu ...`

Comment: @steeldriver I removed the <user> `(ubuntu) CMD (export DISPLAY=:10 /bin/sh /ibc.paper/twsstart.sh > /ibc.paper/logs/cron
Jun 14 18:25:01 CRON[1617]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)` same error am I missing a `>` where I specify log file? Thanks

Comment: ... your redirections are OK I think - the issue may be that your user can't write to `/ibc.paper/logs/` ?

Comment: @steeldriver double checked that I do have permission...thinking what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: export has the format `export name[=word]`, so it means you are trying  to export the names DISPLAY, /bin/sh,  /path/to/script/script.sh